# Google search results show Salesforce logo instead of Experience Cloud branding logo

Tags: community, seo

We run different communities in different Salesforce orgs. The community is "correctly" included in the Google search results, but the blue cloud of Salesforce is displayed instead of our company logo. The branding set is fine and the desired company logo is stored in the meta tags, the SEO Snapshot is up-to-date. The correct logo appears in the browser tab, but not in the Google Search results.

Community
https://de.deutschepost.de/einfacherversenden/s/

Google Search
https://www.google.de/search?safe=active&safe=active&q=einfacher+versenden

***What could be the reason for this?***

All the best, Martin

[image]

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, in incognito mode it still occurs

Comment: I tried in Chrome and Firefox but could not replicate the Salesforce blue cloud logo. Google search results also show the company logo.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search perhaps this will help?